# SSRS with Snowflake

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssrs-2012

We have many Scheduled, and User-Run SSRS Reports that were running against a SQL Server Database.

Since we have moved our Production DB to Snowflake, we want to recreate the reports to get their data from Snowflake.

As a first step, I have re-worked the SQL in a 3rd Party SQL Query Designer named 'DataView' to pull in the required data from Snowflake.

The next thing I have done is use 'OpenQuery...' syntax in an SSRS report to create a very basic SSRS report.

Here's the Dataset syntax:

```
Select * From OPENQUERY 
    (
    SNOWFLAKE, 
    '
    Select Top 10 CAST(FirstName as VARCHAR(8000)) as FirstName 
    From DB_Name.Schema_Name.Patient
    ORDER BY FirstName
    '
    )
```

This works fine in SSRS but I have a few questions.

The actual SQL I will be using is around 350 lines long.
Do I have to Cast each String value as Varchar(8000) in order for the SSRS report to run?
How do I pass Start Date and End Date variables into the SSRS report to filter the output?
What is the ideal way to use Snowflake SQL to create a report for Users to run with their own Date Range?

If SSRS [using OpenQuery syntax] is not the most elegant way to create User-Run reports, I'd like to know what IS the best Reporting tool [Power BI?] to use.

I'd appreciate any pointers I can get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the cast is "in the snowflake side SQL" as it appears, you do not need to cast it, unless you want to truncate, at which point a `left(firstname, 8000)` would make more sense, OR if it's varaint data, it makes more sense to do a Snowflake cast like `firstname::text` or `firstname::varchar` but it's it's already text type, just selecting it should be enough

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server Linked Server instead of connecting directly to Snowflake with their ODBC driver? https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/odbc/odbc-download

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim: If I just select the column, I get the following error: "Cannot read the next data row for the dataset 'Dataset_Name'
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].FIRSTNAME" from OLEDB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SNOWFLAKE". 
OLEDB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SNOWFLAKE" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported."."

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I am using the SQL Server Linked Server because we are learning this process by trial and error and that is what a colleague marked as 'working'. While it IS 'working', it is proving to be extremely unwieldy and fraught with limitations like not 'liking' certain Snowflake  functions like 'CONCAT()' and having to use escape single-quotes wherever Snowflake SQL uses single-quotes for string values. Is your question suggesting that using the Snowflake ODBC driver will be a better option? I am trying to learn the best way to create reports using our Snowflake SQL.

Comment: Yes, connecting directly to Snowflake should work better.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Is there any documentation on how to do this? I've watched a couple of videos and read a few articles ... but they all seem to gravitate to using a Linked Server and Openquery. I'd appreciate any help/pointers you can give me.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Following your suggestion, we installed and are using the Snowflake ODBC Driver and we no long have the need to Cast all the text columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to Snowflake in a paginated report, install the [Snowflake ODBC driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/odbc/odbc)

Create 64-bit system DSN following the directions in the Snowflake documentation.

Then in PowerBI Report builder (or SSRS Report Builder) create a data source referencing that DSN:

[image]

and set the credentials

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Will this method work with SSRS?

Comment: Yes.  It will work identically on SSRS.